# Error al guardar datos con ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb, datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un error y es para almacenar unos datos. No me permite guardarlos ya que aparece esto. Aquí dejo el codigo.

```vb
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Public Class Proveedor

    Private idProveedor As Integer
    Private marcaProducto As String
    Private proveedorProducto As String
    Public mensaje As String = ""
    Private Cnn As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("StrConexion")
    Private conexion As New SqlConnection(Cnn)
        Private Sub Conectar()
            If conexion.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conexion.Open()
            End If
        End Sub
        Private Sub Desconectar()
            If conexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conexion.Close()
            End If
        End Sub
    Function GetidProveedor() As Integer
        Return Me.idProveedor
    End Function
    Function GetmarcaProducto() As String
        Return marcaProducto
    End Function
    Function GetproveedorProducto() As String
        Return proveedorProducto
    End Function
    Sub SetmarcaProducto(ByVal marcaProducto As String)
        Me.marcaProducto = marcaProducto
    End Sub
    Sub SetproveedorProducto(ByVal proveedorProducto As String)
        Me.proveedorProducto = proveedorProducto
    End Sub
    Public Sub GuardarProveedor()
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand
        Dim drConsulta As SqlDataReader
        Dim cadSQL As String = ""
        Dim NuevoID As Integer
        cadSQL = "insert into Proveedor values('" & marcaProducto & "', '" & proveedorProducto & "')"
        Conectar()
        cmdSQL = New SqlCommand(cadSQL, conexion)
        cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Desconectar()
        cadSQL = "Select top 1 idProveedor from Proveedor order by idProveedor desc"
        Conectar()
        cmdSQL = New SqlCommand(cadSQL, conexion)
        drConsulta = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        If (drConsulta.Read) Then
            NuevoID = drConsulta.Item("idProveedor")
        End If
        Desconectar()
        mensaje = "Proveedor almacenado satisfactoriamente"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Es para un proyecto de mis estudios, y solo necesito almacenar este "proveedor" pues la manera de hacerlo es mediante forms. Se encuentran los dos textbox, y el botón de registrar con el siguiente código:

```vb
public Class Proveedor1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim newproveedor As New Proveedor
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnRegistrarProveedor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrarProveedor.Click
        newproveedor.SetmarcaProducto(txtmarcaProducto.Text)
        newproveedor.SetproveedorProducto(txtproveedorProducto.Text)
        newproveedor.GuardarProveedor()
    End Sub
End Class
```

pero al oprimir el botón para registrar me aparece un error tal como muestra en la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

dado a que no colocas el detalle de las columnas de tu tabla Proveedor supongo que no estas colocando todas las columnas en tu insert.

Puedes revisar el siguiente enlace para la estructura de la sentencia insert
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Adicionalmente te recomiendo revisar el uso de parámetros en lugar de concatenar los datos en el query, ya que puedes ser propenso a SQL Injection.